# Why applying Array.of() to Object creates Number in JavaScript/ECMAScript

Tags: javascript

I was reading ES spec and found that `Array.of()` uses `this` to create a new instance.

[22.1.2.3 Array.of ( ...items )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.of)

> Note 2: The `of` function is an intentionally generic factory method; it does not require that its `this` value be the Array constructor. Therefore it can be transferred to or inherited by other constructors that may be called with a single numeric argument.

Then I tried to create using `Object` as `this`, as following. However, it creates `Number` instance while the others like `Date`, `RegExp` or my classes create own instances.

```
const arr = Array.of.apply(Object, ['Hey']);

console.log(arr instanceof Number); // => true
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.apply(arr)); // => '[object Number]'
```

Why is this `arr` not instance of `Object` but `Number`?

Spec: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-array.of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the spec:

```
4. If IsConstructor(C) is true, then
  a. Let A be ? Construct(C, « len »).
```

Given that `C` is `Object` and you are passing one argument to `Array.of`, this is the same as doing

```
new Object(1)
```

which returns a Number object (because that's how `Object` is defined).